# how to reread the file configed in server.xml without restart tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, https

[image]

Recently, I got a mission to set up an https server with tomcat, with bidirectional authentication. I have to write the cert into the trustKeyStoreFile. But the user still cannot visit the website without restarting tomcat.

I think it is because tomcat reads the file when it starts. So even if I write the cert into the trustKeyStoreFile, the cert is still not trusted.

I cannot restart the server every time there is a new user, so how can I let the server reread the file when it is changed?

Comment: Please add the source in s code-block, not as screenshot!

Comment: You shouldn't add a new certificate every time a new user is created. Please see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Certificates.

Comment: I got a solution for this and would like to share if anyone else has the same problem .You can change the truststoreFile to trustManagerClassName in the server.xml .And write a class implements X509TrustManager and pack it into a jar file and put it into the lib folder of tomcat.